# Evitar que el evento click se ejecute dos veces

Tags: jquery

Buen día tengo este código jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".like").click(function(){
        var id = this.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: "megusta.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id:id},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                var likes = data["likes"];
                var text = data["text"];

                $("#likes_" + id).text(likes);
                $("#" + id).html(text);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Estoy haciendo un tipo facebook, entonces cuando doy click en me gusta cambia a ya no me gusta pero cuando doy click nuevamente para que cambie a me gusta, es cuando viene el problema, el evento click se ejecuta dos veces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buen día, puedes usar "one" en lugar de ".click" en el listener del evento como te muestro a continuación:

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

Para el caso del código que compartes quedaría algo como lo siguiente:

```
$(".like").one("click",function(){
    var id = this.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: "megusta.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id:id},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                var likes = data["likes"];
                var text = data["text"];

                $("#likes_" + id).text(likes);
                $("#" + id).html(text);
            }
        });
});
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Solución sencilla y efectiva. Además de esto yo deshabilitaría el botón (o simularía el efecto, si no fuese un botón) para dejar claro al usuario que no se puede pulsar más de una vez.

Comment: Gracias pero no funciona como yo quiero, mira el asunto es que estoy haciendo un tipo facebook, entonces cuando doy click en me gusta cambia a ya no me gusta pero cuando doy click nuevamente para que cambie a me gusta, es cuando viene el problema, el evento click se ejecuta dos veces

Comment: @Alex esa explicación la debes hacer en la pregunta para dejar claro lo que quieres hacer...

Comment: porque no consultar primero el estatus del flag "ME GUSTA"? y posterior a eso ejecutar una acción. Es decir si se encuentra en 1 lo descoloreas y si se encuentra en 0 lo coloreas

Answer (score 5):

Bueno hice esto y me ha dado resultado

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".like").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var id = this.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: "megusta.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id:id},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                var likes = data["likes"];
                var text = data["text"];

                $("#likes_" + id).text(likes);
                $("#" + id).html(text);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Si alguien tiene otra solución que quisiera compartir se lo agradecería!!!!

Answer (score -2):

Gracias me resultó tu ejemplo con:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```